# Cannot find selected value of dynamically added controls in repeater

Tags: asp.net, controls, repeater, radiobuttonlist, findcontrol

I am creating a survey page that has a list of questions and answers that can be radiobuttonlists, checkboxlists or textboxes. These controls are added dynamically to a Repeater in its ItemDataBound event using Controls.Add.

I've managed to render the page ok but when I submit the form and iterate over the controls in the repeater to get the selectedvalues of the radiobuttons and textbox values, FindControl returns null. What do I need to do to get get the selected values? I've tried iterating over the RepeaterItems but that returned null too. I've tried different types of FindControl but it never resolves the control types.
It works if I add a declarative DataBinder in the Repeater like this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptSurvey" runat="server" Visible="true" EnableViewState="true" >
 <ItemTemplate>
      <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Question") %>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

However, I want want to dynamically add the controls but in doing this i cant get the selectedvalues when submitting. This is tha main structure of my code...

```
<html>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptSurvey" runat="server" Visible="true">                      
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</html>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  ...

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                rptSurvey.DataSource = GetQuestions();
                rptSurvey.DataBind();
            }
  ...

}

protected void rptSurvey_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                string question = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Question")).ToString();

              litQuestion = new Literal();
                litQuestion.Text = question;
        RadioButtonList rblAnswer = (RadioButtonList)item;


                    rptSurvey.Controls.Add(rblAnswer);
    }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
           ...
            Dictionary<int, string> answers = new Dictionary<int, string>();

            try
            {
                var list = FindControls(rptSurvey, c => c is RadioButtonList || c is CheckBoxList || c is TextBox);

                foreach (Control item in list)
                {
                    QuestionId = int.Parse(Questions.Rows[list.IndexOf(item)][0].ToString());

                    if (item is TextBox)
                    {
                        TextBox txtAnswer = (TextBox)item;
                        answers.Add(QuestionId, txtAnswer.Text);
                    }
                    else if (item is RadioButtonList)
                    {
                        RadioButtonList rblAnswer = (RadioButtonList)item;
                        answers.Add(QuestionId, rblAnswer.SelectedItem.Text);
                    }

                    else if (item is CheckBoxList)
                    {
                        // Iterate through the Items collection of the CheckBoxList 
                        string cblMultiAnswer = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < cblAnswer.Items.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (cblAnswer.Items[i].Selected)
                            {
                                cblMultiAnswer += cblAnswer.Items[i].Value + ",";
                            }
                        }

                        answers.Add(QuestionId, cblMultiAnswer);
                    }
                }

               bSurvey.BLInsertSurveyAnswers(answers, dateCreated, _userEmail);
            }
        }

        public static List<Control> FindControls(Control parent, Predicate<Control> match)
        {
            var list = new List<Control>();
            foreach (Control ctl in parent.Controls)
            {
                if (match(ctl))
                    list.Add(ctl);
                list.AddRange(FindControls(ctl, match));
            }
            return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create the control tree first (always - not only on non-postbacks). do it in the oninit or onpreload event.

look here: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131055/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081402-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks karlis, the page and its controls render ok. Its when I try to enumerate over the controls to get their values that they are null. I thought by adding the controls OnItemDataBound would take care of creating the control tree and as far as I can see the control tree is there. Am I missing something else fundamental?

Comment: have you changed your code to build the controltree always? maybe you update your code in the inital post....

Comment: i have had another look at your sourcecode: rptSurvey.Controls.Add(rblAnswer) -> i don't think thats ok, you are adding to the repeater, but you should add to the item, -> e.Item.Controls.Add(rblAnswer)

Comment: and var list = FindControls(rptSurvey, c => c is RadioButtonList || c is CheckBoxList || c is TextBox); -> seems also not to be the right way. you search only in the repeater-control with your find method, but you also have to search the childcontrols. that can be done with your findcontrol method, make it a recursive call. but, if you change that you use the rep-item-control to add your contr, than you can just iterate over the repeater-items and get the controls via foreach (RepeaterItem repItem in repAreas.Items)
            {
                var lbl = repItem.FindControl("lbl") as Label;

Comment: The FindControls method I use is recursive - it builds a list of all the matching controls below the parent (rptSurvey). I could use repItems.Items and you're probably right about using e.Item.Controls.Add...I'll see if it works.

Comment: Recursive: the method will call itself under specified conditions

Comment: Thank you karlis, you've set me on the right path after two  lost days! I moved the DataBind() out of the !IsPostBack in Page_Load() and built the control tree using e.Items.Control.Add(ctrl) as you advised. Time to go kick myself and read about page lifecycle, again. By the way, the recursive findcontrol method I use works well. Thanks again, much appreciated.

Comment: ok, ah, i saw now that the method is recursive, was too late for me. :)